# Graph Data Structures using C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, dijkstra

I am making a console application that will print all the paths. But I am having a hard time thinking on how to display all paths from source to destination.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int arr[8][8] = {{50,30,45,120,0,7,0,0},{30,45,28,4,70,0,0,0},
{50,20,0,38,0,0,0,0},{0,4,30,0,52,0,3,0},{0,75,0,27,0,2,0,3},
{70,0,0,0,2,0,2,0},{0,80,0,73,0,2,0,0},{60,0,90,0,30,0,0,0}};
char vertex[8] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'};

void displayPath()
{
    system("cls");
    int start, end;
    char from, to;

    cout << "From vertex: ";
    cin >> from;
    cout << "To: ";
    cin >> to;

   switch(from)
   {
        case 'a':case 'A': start = 0; break;
        case 'b':case 'B': start = 1; break;
        case 'c':case 'C': start = 2; break;
        case 'd':case 'D': start = 3; break;
        case 'e':case 'E': start = 4; break;
        case 'f':case 'F': start = 5; break;
        case 'g':case 'G': start = 6; break;
        case 'h':case 'H': start = 7; break;    

    }

    switch(to)
   {
        case 'a':case 'A': end = 0; break;
        case 'b':case 'B': end = 1; break;
        case 'c':case 'C': end = 2; break;
        case 'd':case 'D': end = 3; break;
        case 'e':case 'E': end = 4; break;
        case 'f':case 'F': end = 5; break;
        case 'g':case 'G': end = 6; break;
        case 'h':case 'H': end = 7; break;
   }

    int temp = 0;
    int current = start;

    if(arr[start][end] > 0)
    {
        cout << vertex[start] << "->" << vertex[end];
    }
    else
        cout << "No path";
}

void computeDistance()
{
    system("cls");
    int start,end;
    char from, to;

    cout << "From vertex: ";
    cin >> from;
    cout << "To: ";
    cin >> to;

    switch(from)
    {
        case 'a':case 'A': start = 0; break;
        case 'b':case 'B': start = 1; break;
        case 'c':case 'C': start = 2; break;
        case 'd':case 'D': start = 3; break;
        case 'e':case 'E': start = 4; break;
        case 'f':case 'F': start = 5; break;
        case 'g':case 'G': start = 6; break;
        case 'h':case 'H': start = 7; break;    
    }

    switch(to)
    {
        case 'a':case 'A': end = 0; break;
        case 'b':case 'B': end = 1; break;
        case 'c':case 'C': end = 2; break;
        case 'd':case 'D': end = 3; break;
        case 'e':case 'E': end = 4; break;
        case 'f':case 'F': end = 5; break;
        case 'g':case 'G': end = 6; break;
        case 'h':case 'H': end = 7; break;
    }

    if(arr[start][end] > 0)
    {
        cout << arr[start][end] << " meters" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "No path";
 }

int main()
{
    int choice;

    cout << "Menu\n\n[1] Display Path\n[2] Compute Distance\n\nChoice: ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1: displayPath(); break;
        case 2: computeDistance(); break;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This program only gives the source to destination, not all the vertices passed through. This should be the sample output:

```
From: A
To: F

A -> B -> D -> F
```

Also, it should follow the concept of shortest path. And will give the total distance. I hope you could help me with this one. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to implement some algorithm which will find shortest path.
Basically there are couple choices:

- [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)
- [A* search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

I don't see you have implemented anything which do such search.

Answer (score 0):

The number of various paths between 2 nodes in graph is exponential. That means that there can be a lot of them.
I am not sure if your graph is always built of 8 nodes. In the following solution I have assumed that it is.

1. Having such a small data you can use very slow and not efficient solutions.
2. Example: Lets generate every possible permutation of nodes and check all which start from source and check them until they reach destination.
3. Getting shortest path after checking all paths is pretty easy - just count total distance of each path while checking them.

Some code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int Graph[8][8];
map <int, bool> used; // to not print same path multiple times


int valid_path(int src, int dest, vector<int>& path)
{
    int pathHash=0;
    if (path[0]!=src) return -1;
    for (size_t i=1; i<path.size(); i++)
    {
        pathHash= pathHash*10+path[i]; // such solution works only because of small size of data
        if (Graph[path[i-1]][path[i]]==0) return -1; // there is no edge between these nodes
        if (path[i]==dest) break;

    }
    return pathHash;
}

void print_path (int dest, vector<int>& path)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<path.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << path[i] << " ";
        if (path[i]==dest) break;
        cout << " --> ";
    }
}

void generate_paths(int src, int dest)
{
    vector<int> perm {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    do
    {
        int pathHash= valid_path(src, dest, perm);
        if (pathHash!=-1 && used[pathHash]==false)
        {
            used[pathHash]=true;
            print_path(dest, perm);
            cout << "\n";
        }
    } while (next_permutation(perm.begin(), perm.end()));
}


int main () {
    for (size_t i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j=0; j<8; j++)
        {
            cin >> Graph[i][j];
        }
    }
    generate_paths(0, 7);
}

/* example input
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
*/
```